# Sort by ID when ID < 1000, otherwise sort by name

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of Ids and Names. Where the Id is less than 1000, I want to order by Id. Otherwise sort by Names. For example, if I have:

```
Id   Name
2    A
1    B
3    C
1111 Z
2222 Y
3333 X
```

The result should be (first three rows sorted by Id, last three rows sorted by Name):

```
Id   Name
1    B
2    A
3    C
3333 A
1111 B
2222 C
```

I came up with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
  CASE Id
    WHEN Id < 1000 THEN
        Id
    ELSE
        Name
  END
  ASC
;
```

Which isn't really working - for the following table:

```
Id   Name
1    M
2    P
3    A1
4    C
5    A2
6    T
1009 A2
1011 A1
1010 A3
```

I get the following output:

```
1    M
3    A1
1011 A1
5    A2
1009 A2
1010 A3
4    C
2    P
6    T
```

What's happening here? And what's the correct query I'm after?

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END, Name`

Comment: What you had should work too if you removed the extra ID there (before the WHEN: `ORDER BY CASE  WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE Name END`
But I would like to mix numbers and text like that

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You mean that you *wouldn't* like to mix numbers and text like that?

Comment: @Colin'tHart correct. silly TypoCube ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ypercubeᵀᴹ has the correct answer in a comment.

To have this always be correct -- including cases when the names start with digits -- you need to have a two column order by clause as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id ELSE 1000 END,
  Name;
```

Observe that all Id's above 1000 are assigned the same value so that then the second column comes into play.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I'm quite new to this, where is this assigning the value 1000 to the Id where Id > 1000? I'm guessing it's the `ELSE 1000 END` part, but I just don't see it - how does this work? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the `case` expression works much like an `if` statement in all programming languages: the `else` part fires when none of the other expressions have matched. So when Id is less than 1000 we return that value, otherwise we use 1000. And no need to apologise: we all started somewhere.

Comment: So when Id >= 1000, 1000 is "returned", I get that. But in my mind, it turns into `ORDER BY 1000, Name;`. This is obviously wrong since there is no 1000th column. There is something I'm not getting, how is 1000 assigned to Id?

Comment: The 1000 is used only by the ORDER BY. All rows with id < 1000 come first, then the rows with 1000 at the end. And because they are tied, the tie is resolved by the second column (in the ORDER BY), which is Name.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing about, this seems to work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN Id < 1000 THEN Id
    WHEN Id > 1000 THEN Name
  END
  ASC
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if you have names starting with digits; you have a single column in your `order by` clause and you are coercing them to the same datatype.